# Generating unique, ordered Pythagorean triplets

Tags: python, math

This is a program I wrote to calculate Pythagorean triplets. When I run the program it prints each set of triplets twice because of the if statement. Is there any way I can tell the program to only print a new set of triplets once? Thanks.

```
import math

def main():
    for x in range (1, 1000):
        for y in range (1, 1000):
            for z in range(1, 1000):
                if x*x == y*y + z*z:
                    print y, z, x
                    print '-'*50

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Is that for Project Euler problem 9?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Pythagorean Triples make a good example for claiming "**`for` loops considered harmful**", because `for` loops seduce us into thinking about counting, often the most irrelevant part of a task.

(I'm going to stick with pseudo-code to avoid language biases, and to keep the pseudo-code streamlined, I'll not optimize away multiple calculations of e.g. `x * x` and `y * y`.)

**Version 1**:

```
for x in 1..N {
    for y in 1..N {
        for z in 1..N {
            if x * x + y * y == z * z then {
                // use x, y, z
            }
        }
    }
}
```

is the worst solution. It generates duplicates, and traverses parts of the space that aren't useful (e.g. whenever `z < y`). Its time complexity is cubic on `N`.

**Version 2**, the first improvement, comes from requiring `x < y < z` to hold, as in:

```
for x in 1..N {
    for y in x+1..N {
        for z in y+1..N {
            if x * x + y * y == z * z then {
                // use x, y, z
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which reduces run time and eliminates duplicated solutions. However, it is still cubic on `N`; the improvement is just a reduction of the co-efficient of `N`-cubed.

It is pointless to continue examining increasing values of `z` after `z * z < x * x + y * y` no longer holds. That fact motivates **Version 3**, the first step away from brute-force iteration over `z`:

```
for x in 1..N {
    for y in x+1..N {
        z = y + 1
        while z * z < x * x + y * y {
            z = z + 1
        }
        if z * z == x * x + y * y and z <= N then {
            // use x, y, z
        }
    }
}
```

For `N` of 1000, this is about 5 times faster than Version 2, but it is *still* cubic on `N`.

The next insight is that `x` and `y` are the only independent variables; `z` depends on their values, and the last `z` value considered for the previous value of `y` is a good *starting* search value for the next value of `y`. That leads to **Version 4**:

```
for x in 1..N {
    y = x+1
    z = y+1
    while z <= N {
        while z * z < x * x + y * y {
            z = z + 1
        }
        if z * z == x * x + y * y and z <= N then {
            // use x, y, z
        }
        y = y + 1
    }
}
```

which allows `y` and `z` to "sweep" the values above `x` only once. Not only is it over 100 times faster for `N` of 1000, it is quadratic on `N`, so the speedup increases as `N` grows.

I've encountered this kind of improvement often enough to be mistrustful of "counting loops" for any but the most trivial uses (e.g. traversing an array).

**Update:** Apparently I should have pointed out a few things about V4 that are easy to overlook.

1. **Both** of the `while` loops are controlled by the value of `z` (one directly, the other indirectly through the square of `z`). The inner `while` is actually speeding up the outer `while`, rather than being orthogonal to it. *It's important to look at what the loops are doing, not merely to count how many loops there are.*
2. All of the calculations in V4 are strictly integer arithmetic. Conversion to/from floating-point, as well as floating-point calculations, are costly by comparison.
3. V4 runs in constant memory, requiring only three integer variables. There are no arrays or hash tables to allocate and initialize (and, potentially, to cause an out-of-memory error).
4. The original question allowed all of `x`, `y`, and `x` to vary over the same range. V1..V4 followed that pattern.

Below is a not-very-scientific set of timings (using Java under Eclipse on my older laptop with other stuff running...), where the "use x, y, z" was implemented by instantiating a Triple object with the three values and putting it in an ArrayList. (For these runs, `N` was set to 10,000, which produced 12,471 triples in each case.)

```
Version 4:           46 sec.
using square root:  134 sec.
array and map:      400 sec.
```

The "array and map" algorithm is *essentially*:

```
squares = array of i*i for i in 1 .. N
roots = map of i*i -> i for i in 1 .. N
for x in 1 .. N
    for y in x+1 .. N
        z = roots[squares[x] + squares[y]]
        if z exists use x, y, z
```

The "using square root" algorithm is *essentially*:

```
for x in 1 .. N
    for y in x+1 .. N
        z = (int) sqrt(x * x + y * y)
        if z * z == x * x + y * y then use x, y, z
```

The actual code for V4 is:

```
public Collection<Triple> byBetterWhileLoop() {
    Collection<Triple> result = new ArrayList<Triple>(limit);
    for (int x = 1; x < limit; ++x) {
        int xx = x * x;
        int y = x + 1;
        int z = y + 1;
        while (z <= limit) {
            int zz = xx + y * y;
            while (z * z < zz) {++z;}
            if (z * z == zz && z <= limit) {
                result.add(new Triple(x, y, z));
            }
            ++y;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note that `x * x` *is* calculated in the outer loop (although I didn't bother to cache `z * z`); similar optimizations are done in the other variations.

I'll be glad to provide the Java source code on request for the other variations I timed, in case I've mis-implemented anything.

Comment: In your version 4 you *still* have 3 embedded loops, so calculating the first 10.000 Pythagore triplets will literally take days.  You may want to check out ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ's algorithm or mine for a 2 loops solution.

Comment: You don't understand how V4 differs from V1-V3. It took 49 seconds on my laptop to calculate the first 12471 triples. Both "while" loops are testing on z's value.

Comment: @joel: I must admit that I have trouble understanding your algorithm, but I just ran it and it took 61 seconds to calculate pythagore_triplets_v4(10000), so I believe you: it looks like it's quadratic.  But still your algorithm is 50% slower than my "array and map" algorithm.

Comment: @joel: it's interesting how there are apparently huge differences in performance between python and Java: according to your results above, no further discussion is need, your v4 algorithm is perfect.  But with python, v4 is 50% slower than my "array&map" algorithm.  In general I would recommend v4.

Comment: @joel: I finally understand this algorithm.  Took me some time.  ;-)  Nice work.

Comment: Would you like to compare in Java my V.2 (or possibly V.3) algorithm to your V4? Converting your V4 to Python it seems that my V.2 is ~1.7× faster than yours, so I'd like to know what happens in the Java side of things. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 51):

Substantially faster than any of the solutions so far. Finds triplets via a ternary tree.

[Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PythagoreanTriple.html) says:

> Hall (1970) and Roberts (1977) prove that `(a, b, c)` is a primitive Pythagorean triple if and only if
>
> ```
> (a,b,c)=(3,4,5)M
> ```
>
> where `M` is a finite product of the matrices `U`, `A`, `D`.

And there we have a formula to generate every primitive triple.

In the above formula, the hypotenuse is ever growing so it's pretty easy to check for a max length.

In Python:

```
import numpy as np

def gen_prim_pyth_trips(limit=None):
    u = np.mat(' 1  2  2; -2 -1 -2; 2 2 3')
    a = np.mat(' 1  2  2;  2  1  2; 2 2 3')
    d = np.mat('-1 -2 -2;  2  1  2; 2 2 3')
    uad = np.array([u, a, d])
    m = np.array([3, 4, 5])
    while m.size:
        m = m.reshape(-1, 3)
        if limit:
            m = m[m[:, 2] <= limit]
        yield from m
        m = np.dot(m, uad)
```

If you'd like all triples and not just the primitives:

```
def gen_all_pyth_trips(limit):
    for prim in gen_prim_pyth_trips(limit):
        i = prim
        for _ in range(limit//prim[2]):
            yield i
            i = i + prim
```

`list(gen_prim_pyth_trips(10**4))` took 2.81 milliseconds to come back with 1593 elements while `list(gen_all_pyth_trips(10**4))` took 19.8 milliseconds to come back with 12471 elements.

For reference, the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/576405/992385) [(in Python)](https://gist.github.com/kgullion/6adc2d633038ff852923) took 38 seconds for 12471 elements.

Just for fun, setting the upper limit to one million `list(gen_all_pyth_trips(10**6))` returns in 2.66 seconds with 1980642 elements (almost 2 million triples in 3 seconds). `list(gen_all_pyth_trips(10**7))` brings my computer to its knees as the list gets so large it consumes every last bit of RAM. Doing something like `sum(1 for _ in gen_all_pyth_trips(10**7))` gets around that limitation and returns in 30 seconds with 23471475 elements.

For more information on the algorithm used, check out the articles on [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PythagoreanTriple.html) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_of_primitive_Pythagorean_triples).

Comment: The most efficient so far. It is python 3 code, to be precise.

Comment: I gave a version without numpy (below in routine pythag3). It gives `t=time();(sum(1 for i in pythag3(10**7,True)),time()-t,"seconds") -> (23471475, 7, "seconds")`

Answer (score 12):

You should define x < y < z.

```
for x in range (1, 1000):
    for y in range (x + 1, 1000):
            for z in range(y + 1, 1000):
```

Another good optimization would be to only use x and y and calculate zsqr = x * x + y * y. If zsqr is a square number (or z = sqrt(zsqr) is a whole number), it is a triplet, else not. That way, you need only two loops instead of three (for your example, that's about 1000 times faster).

Comment: That all makes sense, but check your variable names!  You're getting your x's, y's and z's muddled.  :-)

Comment: Fixed this, thanks. It's now zsqr = x * x + y * y like it should be

Comment: The problem actually definesthat x+y+z=1000 so you eliminate the third loop entirely with a simple z = 1000-x-y

Comment: You do not need 3 embedded loops: check out ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ's algorithm or mine.  If you want to find the first 10.000 Pythagore triplets, our algorithms will save you days of calculations.

Comment: My answer was about the OP's original post, not about Project Euler #9 (he first didn't answer if it is about this problem). In this case you can also use 2 loops and simply exit if x+y+z=1000. Any further optimizations won't mean anything, as the runtime is under a second.

Answer (score 12):

The previously listed algorithms for generating [Pythagorean triplets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triplets) are all modifications of the naive approach derived from the basic relationship `a^2 + b^2 = c^2` where `(a, b, c)` is a triplet of positive integers. It turns out that Pythagorean triplets satisfy some fairly remarkable relationships that can be used to generate all Pythagorean triplets.

[Euclid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid) discovered the first such relationship. He determined that for every Pythagorean triple `(a, b, c)`, possibly after a reordering of `a` and `b` there are relatively prime positive integers `m` and `n` with `m > n`, at least one of which is even, and a positive integer `k` such that

```
a = k (2mn)
b = k (m^2 - n^2)
c = k (m^2 + n^2)
```

Then to generate Pythagorean triplets, generate relatively prime positive integers `m` and `n` of differing parity, and a positive integer `k` and apply the above formula.

```
struct PythagoreanTriple {
    public int a { get; private set; }
    public int b { get; private set; }
    public int c { get; private set; }

    public PythagoreanTriple(int a, int b, int c) : this() {
        this.a = a < b ? a : b;
        this.b = b < a ? a : b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return String.Format("a = {0}, b = {1}, c = {2}", a, b, c);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<PythagoreanTriple> GenerateTriples(int max) {
        var triples = new List<PythagoreanTriple>();
        for (int m = 1; m <= max / 2; m++) {
            for (int n = 1 + (m % 2); n < m; n += 2) {
                if (m.IsRelativelyPrimeTo(n)) {
                    for (int k = 1; k <= max / (m * m + n * n); k++) {
                        triples.Add(EuclidTriple(m, n, k));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return triples;
    }

    private static PythagoreanTriple EuclidTriple(int m, int n, int k) {
        int msquared = m * m;
        int nsquared = n * n;
        return new PythagoreanTriple(k * 2 * m * n, k * (msquared - nsquared), k * (msquared + nsquared));
    }
}

public static class IntegerExtensions {
    private static int GreatestCommonDivisor(int m, int n) {
        return (n == 0 ? m : GreatestCommonDivisor(n, m % n));
    }

    public static bool IsRelativelyPrimeTo(this int m, int n) {
        return GreatestCommonDivisor(m, n) == 1;
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        PythagoreanTriple.GenerateTriples(1000).ToList().ForEach(t => Console.WriteLine(t));            
    }
}
```

The Wikipedia article on [Formulas for generating Pythagorean triples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formulas_for_generating_Pythagorean_triples) contains other such formulae.

Comment: The Ternary Tree method is very good (see the Wikipedia article).

Comment: m <= max / 2 should be optimized to m <= (int) Math.sqrt(max/2). Otherwise this algorithm won't be faster than the ones mentioned above.

Answer (score 8):

Algorithms can be tuned for speed, memory usage, simplicity, and other things.

Here is a `pythagore_triplets` algorithm tuned for speed, at the cost of memory usage and simplicity.  If all you want is speed, this could be the way to go.

Calculation of `list(pythagore_triplets(10000))` takes 40 seconds on my computer, versus 63 seconds for ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ's algorithm, and possibly days of calculation for Tafkas's algorithm (and all other algorithms which use 3 embedded loops instead of just 2).

```
def pythagore_triplets(n=1000):
   maxn=int(n*(2**0.5))+1 # max int whose square may be the sum of two squares
   squares=[x*x for x in xrange(maxn+1)] # calculate all the squares once
   reverse_squares=dict([(squares[i],i) for i in xrange(maxn+1)]) # x*x=>x
   for x in xrange(1,n):
     x2 = squares[x]
     for y in xrange(x,n+1):
       y2 = squares[y]
       z = reverse_squares.get(x2+y2)
       if z != None:
         yield x,y,z

>>> print list(pythagore_triplets(20))
[(3, 4, 5), (5, 12, 13), (6, 8, 10), (8, 15, 17), (9, 12, 15), (12, 16, 20)]
```

Note that if you are going to calculate the first billion triplets, then this algorithm will crash before it even starts, because of an out of memory error.  So ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ's algorithm is probably a safer choice for high values of n.

BTW, here is Tafkas's algorithm, translated into python for the purpose of my performance tests.  Its flaw is to require 3 loops instead of 2.

```
def gcd(a, b):
  while b != 0:
    t = b
    b = a%b
    a = t
  return a

def find_triple(upper_boundary=1000):
  for c in xrange(5,upper_boundary+1):
    for b in xrange(4,c):
      for a in xrange(3,b):
        if (a*a + b*b == c*c and gcd(a,b) == 1):
          yield a,b,c
```

Comment: Square root cost in the Python virtual machine is overrated, but I like your answer.

Comment: BTW, I found a bug in the first version of my algorithm: I needed reverse_squares up to n**2+(n-1)**2, but I only had reverse_squares up to n**2. So I rounded up to 2*(n**2): the bug is fixed.

Comment: Please check GCD for fastest alogirthm in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm

Comment: Pls reread V4 carefully. The outer while tests z, which is ALSO being incremented in the inner while. So the inner while is speeding up the outer one. That's why it's quadratic, not cubic as you seem to think. And V4 doesn't run out of memory if the dictionary gets big.

Comment: I agree with you that the differences in performance between Python and Java are interesting. I suspect the fact that Java handles boxing/unboxing differently for the "hash of square roots" map may be a factor.

Comment: I came up with an algorithm (see V.2 in my answer) which still has minimal memory requirements, is almost 4× faster than my previous suggestion and seems to be 1.64× faster than yours here; you might want to verify in your computer.

Answer (score 6):

```
def pyth_triplets(n=1000):
    "Version 1"
    for x in xrange(1, n):
        x2= x*x # time saver
        for y in xrange(x+1, n): # y > x
            z2= x2 + y*y
            zs= int(z2**.5)
            if zs*zs == z2:
                yield x, y, zs

>>> print list(pyth_triplets(20))
[(3, 4, 5), (5, 12, 13), (6, 8, 10), (8, 15, 17), (9, 12, 15), (12, 16, 20)]
```

V.1 algorithm has monotonically increasing `x` values.

#### EDIT

It seems this question is still alive :)
Since I came back and revisited the code, I tried a second approach which is almost 4 times as fast (about 26% of CPU time for N=10000) as my previous suggestion since it avoids lots of unnecessary calculations:

```
def pyth_triplets(n=1000):
    "Version 2"
    for z in xrange(5, n+1):
        z2= z*z # time saver
        x= x2= 1
        y= z - 1; y2= y*y
        while x < y:
            x2_y2= x2 + y2
            if x2_y2 == z2:
                yield x, y, z
                x+= 1; x2= x*x
                y-= 1; y2= y*y
            elif x2_y2 < z2:
                x+= 1; x2= x*x
            else:
                y-= 1; y2= y*y

>>> print list(pyth_triplets(20))
[(3, 4, 5), (6, 8, 10), (5, 12, 13), (9, 12, 15), (8, 15, 17), (12, 16, 20)]
```

Note that this algorithm has increasing `z` values.

If the algorithm was converted to C —where, being closer to the metal, multiplications take more time than additions— one could minimalise the necessary multiplications, given the fact that the step between consecutive squares is:

> (x+1)² - x² = (x+1)(x+1) - x² = x² + 2x + 1 - x² = 2x + 1

so all of the inner `x2= x*x` and `y2= y*y` would be converted to additions and subtractions like this:

```
def pyth_triplets(n=1000):
    "Version 3"
    for z in xrange(5, n+1):
        z2= z*z # time saver
        x= x2= 1; xstep= 3
        y= z - 1; y2= y*y; ystep= 2*y - 1
        while x < y:
            x2_y2= x2 + y2
            if x2_y2 == z2:
                yield x, y, z
                x+= 1; x2+= xstep; xstep+= 2
                y-= 1; y2-= ystep; ystep-= 2
            elif x2_y2 < z2:
                x+= 1; x2+= xstep; xstep+= 2
            else:
                y-= 1; y2-= ystep; ystep-= 2
```

Of course, in Python the extra bytecode produced actually *slows down* the algorithm compared to version 2, but I would bet (without checking :) that V.3 is faster in C.

Cheers everyone :)

Answer (score 4):

I just extended Kyle Gullion 's answer so that triples are sorted by hypothenuse, then longest side.

It doesn't use numpy, but requires a SortedCollection (or SortedList) such as [this one](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577197-sortedcollection/) (with the addition of a `pop` method).

```py
def pop(self, i):
    rv = self[i]
    self.remove(rv)
    return rv
SortedCollection.pop = pop
```

```
def primitive_triples():
""" generates primitive Pythagorean triplets x<y<z
sorted by hypotenuse z, then longest side y
through Berggren's matrices and breadth first traversal of ternary tree
:see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_of_primitive_Pythagorean_triples
"""
key=lambda x:(x[2],x[1])
triples=SortedCollection(key=key)
triples.insert([3,4,5])
A = [[ 1,-2, 2], [ 2,-1, 2], [ 2,-2, 3]]
B = [[ 1, 2, 2], [ 2, 1, 2], [ 2, 2, 3]]
C = [[-1, 2, 2], [-2, 1, 2], [-2, 2, 3]]

while triples:
    (a,b,c) = triples.pop(0)
    yield (a,b,c)

    # expand this triple to 3 new triples using Berggren's matrices
    for X in [A,B,C]:
        triple=[sum(x*y for (x,y) in zip([a,b,c],X[i])) for i in range(3)]
        if triple[0]>triple[1]: # ensure x<y<z
            triple[0],triple[1]=triple[1],triple[0]
        triples.insert(triple)

def triples():
""" generates all Pythagorean triplets triplets x<y<z 
sorted by hypotenuse z, then longest side y
"""
prim=[] #list of primitive triples up to now
key=lambda x:(x[2],x[1])
samez=SortedCollection(key=key) # temp triplets with same z
buffer=SortedCollection(key=key) # temp for triplets with smaller z
for pt in primitive_triples():
    z=pt[2]
    if samez and z!=samez[0][2]: #flush samez
        while samez:
            yield samez.pop(0)
    samez.insert(pt)
    #build buffer of smaller multiples of the primitives already found
    for i,pm in enumerate(prim):
        p,m=pm[0:2]
        while True:
            mz=m*p[2]
            if mz < z:
                buffer.insert(tuple(m*x for x in p))
            elif mz == z: 
                # we need another buffer because next pt might have
                # the same z as the previous one, but a smaller y than
                # a multiple of a previous pt ...
                samez.insert(tuple(m*x for x in p))
            else:
                break
            m+=1
        prim[i][1]=m #update multiplier for next loops
    while buffer: #flush buffer
        yield buffer.pop(0)
    prim.append([pt,2]) #add primitive to the list
```

the code is available in the [math2 module](https://github.com/goulu/Goulib/blob/master/Goulib/math2.py) of [my Python library](https://github.com/goulu/Goulib). It is tested against some series of the OEIS (code [here](https://github.com/goulu/Goulib/blob/master/examples/oeis.py) at the bottom), which just enabled me to [find a mistake in A121727](https://oeis.org/draft/A121727) :-)

Answer (score 2):

I wrote that program in Ruby and it similar to the python implementation. The important line is:

```
if x*x == y*y + z*z && gcd(y,z) == 1:
```

Then you have to implement a method that return the greatest common divisor (gcd) of two given numbers. A very simple example in Ruby again:

```
def gcd(a, b)
    while b != 0
      t = b
      b = a%b
      a = t
    end
    return a
end
```

The full Ruby methon to find the triplets would be:

```
def find_triple(upper_boundary)

  (5..upper_boundary).each {|c|
    (4..c-1).each {|b|
      (3..b-1).each {|a|
        if (a*a + b*b == c*c && gcd(a,b) == 1)
          puts "#{a} \t #{b} \t #{c}"
        end
      }
    }
  }
end
```

Comment: Just to clarify the GCD step is only necessary if you want to print primitive triplets. If you want any triplet then you shouldn't have this.

Comment: This algorithm uses 3 embedded loops, although only 2 are required (see ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ's algorithm or mine).  This means that if you search the first 10.000 Pythagore triplets, your algorithm will be 10.000 times slower than a "2-loops" algorithm.

Comment: Be careful with this reasoning. The algorithm that I produced above uses a three-loop construct but is approximately three times faster than the two-loop construct used by ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ.

Comment: @Jason: be careful with comparisons, especially when comparing apples and oranges. In addition, MiniQuark's remark was generic and vague enough to be non-refutable (although not necessarily applicable), while yours lacks the numbers and a common runtime environment.

Comment: @ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ: I translated your code to C# and tested them apples to apples.

Answer (score 2):

Old Question, but i'll still input my stuff.
There are two general ways to generate unique pythagorean triples. One Is by Scaling, and the other is by using this archaic formula.

What scaling basically does it take a constant n, then multiply a base triple, lets say 3,4,5 by n. So taking n to be 2, we get 6,8,10 our next triple.

**Scaling**

```
def pythagoreanScaled(n):
    triplelist = []
    for x in range(n):
        one = 3*x
        two = 4*x
        three = 5*x
        triple = (one,two,three)
        triplelist.append(triple)
return triplelist
```

The formula method uses the fact the if we take a number x, calculate 2m, m^2+1, and m^2-1, those three will always be a pythagorean triplet.

**Formula**

```
def pythagoreantriple(n):
    triplelist = []
    for x in range(2,n):
        double = x*2
        minus = x**2-1
        plus = x**2+1
        triple = (double,minus,plus)
        triplelist.append(triple)
    return triplelist
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.

Okay, now you'll want to know why.  Why not just constrain it so that z > y?  Try

```
for z in range (y+1, 1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from  math import sqrt
from itertools import combinations

#Pythagorean triplet - a^2 + b^2 = c^2 for (a,b) <= (1999,1999)
def gen_pyth(n):
if n >= 2000 :
  return
ELEM =   [  [ i,j,i*i + j*j ] for i , j in list(combinations(range(1, n +   1 ), 2)) if sqrt(i*i + j*j).is_integer() ]
print (*ELEM , sep = "\n")


gen_pyth(200)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
for a in range(1,20):
    for b in range(1,20):
        for c in range(1,20):
            if a>b and c and c>b:
                if a**2==b**2+c**2:
                    print("triplets are:",a,b,c)
```

Comment: if you google "Pythagorean triples list"  you will observes a simple property of the triplets: it follows this property  a>b AND c AND c>b. for example (3,4,5) is a triplet. Here a=5,b=3 and c=4. For loop will run from 0 to 20  for value a,b and c. Along with this if conditions will run and check : a>b and c and c>b. When this condition met we will get our triplet for once and not repeated. Understand the  meaning of 4th line. It's kind of intuitive so I can't explain properly

Answer (score 1):

in python we can store square of all numbers in another list.
then find permutation of pairs of all number given
square them
finally check if any pair sum of square matches the squared list

Answer (score 0):

Version 5 to Joel Neely.

Since X can  be max of 'N-2' and Y can be max of 'N-1' for range of 1..N. Since Z max is N and Y max is N-1, X can be max of Sqrt ( N * N - (N-1) * (N-1) ) = Sqrt ( 2 * N - 1 ) and can start from 3.

```
MaxX = ( 2 * N - 1 ) ** 0.5

for x in 3..MaxX {
  y = x+1
  z = y+1
  m = x*x + y*y
  k = z * z
  while z <= N {
     while k < m {
        z = z + 1
        k = k + (2*z) - 1
    }
    if k == m and z <= N then {
        // use x, y, z
    }
    y = y + 1
    m = m + (2 * y) - 1
  }
 }
```

Comment: This algorithm uses 3 embedded loops, although only 2 are required (see ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ's algorithm or mine). This means that if you search the first 10.000 Pythagore triplets, your algorithm will be roughly 10.000 times slower than a "2-loops" algorithm.

Comment: I just optimized joel Neely code further. I will go through your code and i will optimize if required.

Comment: I also checked roughly no of loops and even though it appears to be 3 way loops, total no of statements exectuted is actually less than 2 - looped statement. Please check by putting no of times k is changed or m is changed.

Comment: @lakshmanaraj: MiniQuark didn't understand the relationship between the two while loops (they both are driven by z).

Comment: I've posted the actual code for V4; as you can see, it moves the squaring of x out of the nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

Just checking, but I've been using the following code to make pythagorean triples. It's very fast (and I've tried some of the examples here, though I kind of learned them and wrote my own and came back and checked here (2 years ago)). I think this code correctly finds all pythagorean triples up to (name your limit) and fairly quickly too. I used C++ to make it.

ullong is unsigned long long and I created a couple of functions to square and root
my root function basically said if square root of given number (after making it whole number (integral)) squared not equal number give then return -1 because it is not rootable. 
_square and _root do as expected as of description above, I know of another way to optimize it but I haven't done nor tested that yet.

```
generate(vector<Triple>& triplist, ullong limit) {
cout<<"Please wait as triples are being generated."<<endl;
register ullong a, b, c;
register Triple trip;
time_t timer = time(0);

for(a = 1; a <= limit; ++a) {
    for(b = a + 1; b <= limit; ++b) {
        c = _root(_square(a) + _square(b));

        if(c != -1 && c <= limit) {
            trip.a = a; trip.b = b; trip.c = c;

            triplist.push_back(trip);

        } else if(c > limit)
            break;
    }
}

timer = time(0) - timer;
cout<<"Generated "<<triplist.size()<<" in "<<timer<<" seconds."<<endl;
cin.get();
cin.get();
```

}

Let me know what you all think. It generates all primitive and non-primitive triples according to the teacher I turned it in for. (she tested it up to 100 if I remember correctly).

The results from the v4 supplied by a previous coder here are

Below is a not-very-scientific set of timings (using Java under Eclipse on my older laptop with other stuff running...), where the "use x, y, z" was implemented by instantiating a Triple object with the three values and putting it in an ArrayList. (For these runs, N was set to 10,000, which produced 12,471 triples in each case.)

Version 4:           46 sec.
using square root:  134 sec.
array and map:      400 sec.

The results from mine is
How many triples to generate: 10000

Please wait as triples are being generated.
Generated 12471 in 2 seconds.

That is before I even start optimizing via the compiler. (I remember previously getting 10000 down to 0 seconds with tons of special options and stuff). My code also generates all the triples with 100,000 as the limit of how high side1,2,hyp can go in 3.2 minutes (I think the 1,000,000 limit takes an hour).

I modified the code a bit and got the 10,000 limit down to 1 second (no optimizations). On top of that, with careful thinking, mine could be broken down into chunks and threaded upon given ranges (for example 100,000 divide into 4 equal chunks for 3 cpu's (1 extra to hopefully consume cpu time just in case) with ranges 1 to 25,000 (start at 1 and limit it to 25,000), 25,000 to 50,000 , 50,000 to 75,000, and 75,000 to end. I may do that and see if it speeds it up any (I will have threads premade and not include them in the actual amount of time to execute the triple function. I'd need a more precise timer and a way to concatenate the vectors. I think that if 1 3.4 GHZ cpu with 8 gb ram at it's disposal can do 10,000 as lim in 1 second then 3 cpus should do that in 1/3 a second (and I round to higher second as is atm).

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that for a, b, and c you don't need to loop all the way to N.

For a, you only have to loop from 1 to  `int(sqrt(n**2/2))+1`, for b, `a+1` to `int(sqrt(n**2-a**2))+1`, and for c from `int(sqrt(a**2+b**2)` to `int(sqrt(a**2+b**2)+2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
# To find all pythagorean triplets in a range
import math
n = int(input('Enter the upper range of limit'))
for i in range(n+1):
    for j in range(1, i):
        k = math.sqrt(i*i + j*j)
        if k % 1 == 0 and k in range(n+1):
            print(i,j,int(k))
```

Comment: While this could be a suitable answer to the question, it's helpful to provide a brief description of what your code does rather than just supplying a code-only answer.

Answer (score 0):

U have to use Euclid's proof of Pythagorean triplets. Follow below...

U can choose any arbitrary number greater than zero say `m,n`

According to Euclid the triplet will be `a(m*m-n*n)`, `b(2*m*n)`, `c(m*m+n*n)`

Now apply this formula to find out the triplets, say our one value of triplet is 6 then, other two? Ok let’s solve...

`a(m*m-n*n)`, `b(2*m*n)` , `c(m*m+n*n)`

It is sure that `b(2*m*n)` is obviously even. So now

`(2*m*n)=6 =>(m*n)=3 =>m*n=3*1 =>m=3,n=1`

U can take any other value rather than 3 and 1, but those two values should hold the product of two numbers which is 3 `(m*n=3)`

Now, when `m=3` and `n=1` Then,

`a(m*m-n*n)=(3*3-1*1)=8` , `c(m*m-n*n)=(3*3+1*1)=10`

6,8,10 is our triplet for value, this our visualization of how generating triplets.

if given number is odd like `(9)` then slightly modified here, because `b(2*m*n)`

will never be odd. so, here we have to take

`a(m*m-n*n)=7`, `(m+n)*(m-n)=7*1`, So, `(m+n)=7`, `(m-n)=1`

Now find m and n from here, then find the other two values.

If u don’t understand it, read it again carefully.

Do code according this, it will generate distinct triplets efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

A non-numpy version of the Hall/Roberts approach is

```
def pythag3(limit=None, all=False):
    """generate Pythagorean triples which are primitive (default)
    or without restriction (when ``all`` is True). The elements
    returned in the tuples are sorted with the smallest first.

    Examples
    ========

    >>> list(pythag3(20))
    [(3, 4, 5), (8, 15, 17), (5, 12, 13)]
    >>> list(pythag3(20, True))
    [(3, 4, 5), (6, 8, 10), (9, 12, 15), (12, 16, 20), (8, 15, 17), (5, 12, 13)]

    """
    if limit and limit < 5:
        return
    m = [(3,4,5)]  # primitives stored here
    while m:
        x, y, z = m.pop()
        if x > y:
            x, y = y, x
        yield (x, y, z)
        if all:
            a, b, c = x, y, z
            while 1:
                c += z
                if c > limit:
                    break
                a += x
                b += y
                yield a, b, c
        # new primitives
        a = x - 2*y + 2*z, 2*x - y + 2*z, 2*x - 2*y + 3*z
        b = x + 2*y + 2*z, 2*x + y + 2*z, 2*x + 2*y + 3*z
        c = -x + 2*y + 2*z, -2*x + y + 2*z, -2*x + 2*y + 3*z
        for d in (a, b, c):
            if d[2] <= limit:
                m.append(d)
```

It's slower than the numpy-coded version but the primitives with largest element less than or equal to `10^6` are generated on my slow machine in about 1.4 seconds. (And the list `m` never grew beyond 18 elements.)

Generation of primitive triples depends on generating coprime pairs of numbers, `m` and `n`, with `m>n` and one of them even. (If they are not coprime, the gcd of them can be removed; if they are coprime but both odd then a new pair with a smaller largest value can be defined, `(M=(m+n)/2, N=(m-n)/2)`.) The [Farey method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45699954/1089161) is a fast method of generating coprimes and a few simple checks of the values generated can pass over values that are not of interest as in

```py
from math import sqrt
def primitives(N):
  F = farey(int(math.sqrt(N-1)))
  has0 = next(F) # ignore (0,1)
  for i, j in F:
      if i%2 != j%2 and (c:=i**2+j**2) <= N:
          yield tuple(sorted((2*i*j, j**2-i**2))+[c])
```

This ends up being about 10X faster than `pythag3` but uses O(N) memory.

For clarity in essential ideas behind generating the primitives and brevity of presentation, it is hard to beat the following (which is almost 40% faster than pythag3):

```py
from math import gcd, sqrt
def py3(N):
    for m in range(1, int(sqrt(N - 1)) + 1):
        m2 = m*m
        for n in range(1 + m%2, m, 2):
            n2 = n*n
            if (c := n2 + m2) > N:
                break
            if gcd(m, n) == 1:
                # m-n>sqrt(2)*n then m**2-n**2 > 2*m*n
                # but sort instead of calculate
                yield tuple(sorted((2*m*n, m2 - n2)) + [c])
```

The number of primitive triples matches the values given in [A101931](https://oeis.org/A101931) where is also observed that the fraction of primitive triples, T, for a given upper limit for a triple's element, N, is `1/(2*pi)` -- there's just something beautiful about that when thinking about right triangles and unit circles!

Answer (score 0):

In c language -

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("How many triplets needed : \n");
    scanf("%d\n",&n);
    for(int i=1;i<=2000;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i;j<=2000;j++)
        {
            for(int k=j;k<=2000;k++)
            {
                if((j*j+i*i==k*k) && (n>0))
                {
                    printf("%d %d %d\n",i,j,k);
                    n=n-1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
  triplets=[]
    for a in range(1,100):
        for b in range(1,100):
            for c in range(1,100):
                if  a**2 + b**2==c**2:
                    i=[a,b,c]
                    triplets.append(i)
                    for i in triplets:
                          i.sort()
                          if triplets.count(i)>1:
                              triplets.remove(i)
    print(triplets)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.[How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)