# finding pythagorean triples (a,b,c) with a <=200

Tags: algorithm

In my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976466/pythagorean-triples-exercise) on this subject i have made little progress (not blaming anyone except myself!) so i'll try to approach my problem statement differently.

how do i go about writing the algorithm to generate a list of primitive triples?

all i have to start with is:

a) the basic theorem: `a^2 + b^2 = c^2`

b) the fact that the small sides of the triple (a and b) need to be smaller than 'n'

(note: 'n' <= 200 for this purpose)

How do i go about building my loops? Do i need 2 or 3 loops?

a professor gave me some hints but alas i am still lost. I don't know where to start with building my loops. Do i need 2 or 3 loops? do i loop through a and b or do i need to introduce the 'n' variable into a loop of its own? This probably looks like obvious hints to experienced programmers but it seems i need more hand holding still...any help will be appreciated!

> A Pythagorean triple is group of a,b,c
>   where a^2 + b^2 = c^2. you need to
>   find all a,b,c combinations which
>   satisfy the above rule starting a
>   0,0,0 up to 200 ,609,641 The first
>   triple will be [3,4,5] the next will
>   be  [5,12,13] etc.. n is length of the
>   small side a so if n is 5 you need to
>   check all triples with
>   a=1,a=2,a=3,a=4,a=5 and find the two
>   cases shown above as being
>   Pythagorean,

**EDIT**

thanks for all submissions. So this is what i came up with (using python)

```
import math
for a in range (1,200):
    for b in range (a,a*a):
        csqrd = a * a + b * b
        c = math.sqrt(csqrd)
        if math.floor(c) == c:
                print (a,b,int(c))
```

this DOES return the triple (200 ,609,641) where 200 is the upper limit for 'a' but computing the upper limit for 'b' remains tricky. Not sure how i would go about this...suggestions welcome :)

Thanks

Baba

p.s. i'm not looking for a solution but rather help in improving my problem solving skills. (definitely needed :-) )

Comment: You should probably add that `a`, `b` and `c` have to be integers to make it clear for everyone.

Comment: Isn't that assumed in the definition of a Pythagorean triple?

Comment: the question more related to the logic of shelled looping and as such it doesn't matter what the loops are running on, you could just as easy go FOREACH[A-Z]

Comment: Hint:  You should get (200, 9999, 10001).

Answer (score 1):

You only need two loops. Note that `n` is given, meaning you **read it from the keyboard or from a file**.

Once you read `n`, you simply loop `a` from 1, then in that loop you loop `b` from `a`. Then you check if `a <= n` and if `b <= n`. If yes, you check if `a^2 + b^2` is a square (if it can be writen as `c^2` where `c` is an integer). If yes you output the corresponding triplet. You can stop the first loop once `a > n` and the second loop once `b > n`.

Answer (score 1):

To compute the upper limit of `b` ... certainly we can't go past a^2 + b^2 = (b+1)^2, since the gap between successive squares increases.  Now, (b+1)^2 is b^2 + 2b + 1, so we can stop on b when a^2 < 2b + 1.  (In fact, for odd a, the biggest triple is when b = (a^2 - 1)/2, and then a^2 + b^2 = (b+1)^2.)

Let's consider even a.  Then, we need to consider a^2 + b^2 = (b+2)^2, since 2b+1 is necessarily odd.  Now, (b+2)^2 - b^2 = 4b+4, so we're looking at a^2 = 4b+4, or b = (a^2 - 4)/4 as the highest b (and, as before, we know this b works).

Therefore, for given a, you need to check bs up to

(a^2 - 1)/2 (a odd)

(a ^2 - 4)/4 (a even)

Answer (score 0):

leaving the formula and the language alone, you're trying to find every combination of two variables, a and b so...

```
foreach A   
  foreach B  
    foreach C
      do something  with B and A  and eval with c  
    end foreach C  
  end foreach B  
end foreach A
```

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 200; $x++) {
    for ($y = 1; $y <= 200; $y++) {
        for ($z = 1; $z <= 200; $z++) {
            if ($x < $y) {
                if (pow($x, 2) + pow($y, 2) == pow($z, 2)) {
                    echo "$x, $y , $z<br/>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3, 4 , 5
5, 12 , 13
6, 8 , 10
...

81, 108 , 135
84, 112 , 140
84, 135 , 159

Comment: Hi, (6,8,10) is not a primitve triple as it is a multiple of (3,4,5). This is exactly where the exercise gets tricky.

Comment: @all thanks for your input, this got me started again. I'll get back to you once i've done some more testing and looping

Comment: @Baba:  Primitive triples will have no common factor between a, b, and c.  If a and b are relatively prime, c will be relatively prime, and if a and b share a factor so will c.  Therefore, see if gcd(a, b) is 1.

Answer (score 0):

Given any a and b, you can compute what c should be. You can also check if the c you get is a whole number. With that in mind, you need to check all the a and b values and find the ones that give you a whole c number.

This should take just two loops (one for a and one for b). Leave comments if you want more help, and let me know what problems you have.

Answer (score 0):

So Pythagorean tripes luckily have two properties that make this not so bad to solve:

First, all the numbers in a triple have to be integers (that means, you can calculate `a^2 + b^2` and you have a triple if `c^2` is an integer and not a float). Additionally, `c` is bounded by what `a` and `b` are.

So this should inform you how many variables you really have (which will guide your algorithm design - specifically how many for loops you need). The latter piece of information will inform you as to how long of a range you need to iterate over. I've tried to be vague as per your request, but let me know if you'd like anything more specific.

Comment: yes maybe one question: how can i test that sqrt(c) is an int? something like if sqrt(a)%1 == 0 ?

Comment: Some languages, like c# and java i believe, should have a function that checks if a number is an integer. Otherwise, you could do something like round(c) == c or c//1 = c where // is the floor division operator. Depends on what your language has built-in functions for.

Comment: Hi, please have a look at my update if you can. at this stage i have figured out how to build the loops but there remains one problem i can't figure out: how to deal with the upper bound of 'b' in an efficient manner.

Comment: Hey Baba, it seems like you're progressing. As of now, the only thing I can comment on are the loops. However, you have a big problem with the `b` loop. Think again about what the constraint is on `b`. It should be the exact same as the constraint for `a`, hence you can use a similar condition in that for-loop. (*spoiler: it should be the same).

Answer (score 0):

Break the problem into sub problems. The first clue is that you have an upper bound `n` on the value of `c`. Let's start with `c=1` --- so, let's see how many triplets can be formed with:

```
a^2 + b^2 = 1
```

Now, let's set `a = 1 to c-1`. So that means we have to check if `b` is an integer such that `b^2 = c^2 - a^2` and `b^2 = int(b)^2`.