# Pythagorean triplets

Tags: c

Someone asked me a question(asked to him in an interview) that how to find triplets in an integer array A[] which satisfy following condition:

a[i]^2 + a[j]^2 = a[k]^2

i have done it in o(n^2 logn) can it be optimized.

Comment: my approach:
given an array first sort it in o(nlgn) then corresponding to each pair of (i,j) search through binary search technique for (i+j).so i think time is o(nlogn).optimizations required.

Comment: Please consider saving time for your self - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/575117/pythagorean-triplets

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At least you can use hash table to store squares. So search of (i^2+j^2) for each pair will be in O(1) and in overall algorithm will take O(n^2)

Comment: Answer smell? Claiming `O(1)` for something involving hash tables is usually wrong.

Answer (score 1):

A variation of your approach that's O(n^2).

```
def findPythagoreanTriplets(array):
  array = sorted(array)
  for i in range(len(array)):
    k = i + 2
    for j in range(i + 1, len(array)):
      while k < len(array) and (array[k] ** 2 < (array[i] ** 2 + array[j] ** 2)):
        k += 1
      if k < len(array) and (array[k] ** 2 == (array[i] ** 2 + array[j] ** 2)):
        print "%d^2 + %d^2 = %d^2" % (array[i], array[j], array[k])
```

This is Python code, but converting to C shouldn't be hard. (Actually, this question seems language agnostic, so I'm not sure why you've got the c tag...)

This is assuming all of the inputs are non-negative. You could probably make it work for negative integers as well, but you'd need to sort by the squared value, not by the input value (for non-negative numbers they're the equivalent).

Instead of doing a binary search you just do a linear search for k, but you can pick up from where the previous j's search left off, so searching for k is "free".

Answer (score 1):

Well if the size of the array is small, then it can be optimized using hash table.
Here is the c++ code for the same:

```
class Solution
{
public:
    bool checkTriplet(int arr[], int n)
    {
        int maximum = *std::max_element (a, a+n); 

        // Hashing array
        int hash[maximum + 1] = { 0 };
     
        // Increase the count of array elements in hash table
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            hash[arr[i]]++;
     
        // Iterate for all possible a
        for (int i = 1; i < maximum + 1; i++) {
     
            // If a is not there
            if (hash[i] == 0)
                continue;
     
            // Iterate for all possible b
            for (int j = 1; j < maximum + 1; j++) {
     
                // If a and b are same and there is only one a or if there is no b in original array
                if ((i == j && hash[i] == 1) || hash[j] == 0)
                    continue;
     
                // Find c
                int val = sqrt(i * i + j * j);
     
                // If c^2 is not a perfect square
                if ((val * val) != (i * i + j * j))
                    continue;
     
                // If c exceeds the maximum value
                if (val > maximum)
                    continue;
     
                // If there exists c in the original array we have the triplet
                if (hash[val]) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

The time complexity here would be O(maximum*maximum).