# Is Farey Sequence the fastest way to generate coprime pairs?

Tags: algorithm, performance, python-3.x, optimization

I was looking for ways to generate coprime pairs up to a limit and after some searching I found multiple sources telling that Farey's Sequence is the fastest algorithm. Here are a few of those sources: [Stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422830/generating-all-coprime-pairs-within-limits), [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-fastest-algorithms-for-generating-coprime-pairs#).

This is the Farey's algorithm and a simple GCD:

```
from itertools import combinations
from math import gcd

def farey(limit):
    '''Fast computation of Farey sequence as a generator'''
    # n, d is the start fraction n/d (0,1) initially                            
    # N, D is the stop fraction N/D (1,1) initially                             
    pend = []
    n = 0
    d = N = D = 1
    while True:
        mediant_d = d + D
        if mediant_d <= limit:
            mediant_n = n + N
            pend.append((mediant_n, mediant_d, N, D))
            N = mediant_n
            D = mediant_d
        else:
            yield n, d
            if pend:
                n, d, N, D = pend.pop()
            else:
                break

def simple_gcd(limit):
    for A, B in combinations(range(limit+1), 2):
        if gcd(A, B) == 1:
            yield A, B
```

I checked if they produce the same output:

```
>>> count = 0
>>> for i in farey(10000):
    count+=1


>>> count
30397486
>>> count = 0
>>> for i in simple_gcd(10000):
    count+=1


>>> count
30397486
```

They do.

Yet my function is faster (even faster when outside of a function.)

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit("for i in farey(10000):pass", "from __main__ import   farey", number=1)
16.637074244167408
>>> timeit.timeit("for i in simple_gcd(10000):pass", "from __main__ import simple_gcd", number=1)
16.504983127784428
>>> timeit.timeit("for A, B in itertools.combinations(range(10001), 2):\n    if math.gcd(A, B)==1:pass", "import math, itertools", number=1)
15.035244938807324
```

So, is Farey Sequence really the fastest way to generate coprime pairs, and if not, what algorithm should I use?

Comment: `math.gcd` isn't winning because taking GCDs is an efficient way to go about this. `math.gcd` is implemented in C. Even with the advantages of a C implementation, it's barely winning.

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=farey+sequence might offer some interesting trains of thought.

Comment: Performance measures with python have their problems. The language is great for writing code fast, less to write, easy to use and read. But it is definitely not fast. With python you get a massive overhead for management. The time difference you measured is small, could also be the case that it comes from non-algorithm related stuff like the amount of objects python has to manage or so.

Comment: Is it safe to assume the sequence would be faster than gcd in C/C++?