# Condition (a*a + b*b = c*c) satisfies in a list using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, mathematical-expressions

I need to know whether the elements in the list satisfies the condition
 `a*a + b*b = c*c`, where `a`, `b` and `c` are any elements in the following list:

```
original_list =[8,5,73,3,34,4,23,73]
```

Mathematically, `3*3 + 4*4 = 5*5`, but not sure how to traverse the list in python to satisfy that condition.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575117/

Comment: What have you tried for solving that? What is your problem that you encountered? SO is not a service for getting your homework done.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the items from your list using `itertools.combinations`:

```
import itertools

for a, b, c in itertools.combinations(sorted(original_list), 3):
    if a*a + b*b == c*c:
        print("Pythagorean triple found:", a, b, c) # or whaver...
```

Note that I sort the original list before passing it to `combinations`. That ensures that `a <= b <= c`. While we don't really care about the relative order of `a` and `b`, but the fact that `c` is no smaller than either of them is a prerequisite for the test you're doing.

Comment: Nice approach, but note that this may not work as expected if the list contains numbers less than 1.

Comment: @Kasramvd: Hmm, good point. Sorting with `key=abs` should do the trick, I think, though I suspect negatives are unlikely to be valid inputs.

Comment: Just edited the comment by changing the "negative" to "less than one" :) but yes. If it's integer using `key=abs` will do the trick other wise maybe a more complicated key function that can also handles the situations like `0.5 * 0.5 + 0.1 * 0.1 == 0.26`.

Comment: This has really bad complexity; I don't know the formula but I ran couple tests:


    time python -c '
    from itertools import combinations
    i = 0
    for a, b, c in combinations(range(1000), 3):
        i += 1
    print(i)'
    166167000
    python -c   15.44s user 0.01s system 99% cpu 15.466 total

Comment: with better formatting: `python -m timeit -n 1 -s 'from itertools import combinations; i = 0' 'for a, b, c in combinations(range(1000), 3): i+=1' 'print(i)'`

`1 loops, best of 3: 8.43 sec per loop`

Answer (score 1):

This questions revolves more around math and algorithms than pythonisms. The solution I propose below has a complexity in `O(n**2)`.

The idea is to reverse the function (x, y) => x * x + y * y, where the search space is the cross product of the original list with itself. Then, using Python set operators, compute the intersection between the application image and the acceptable squares. Eventually, use the reversed application to reconstruct the triplets.

```
from collections import defaultdict

original_list = [8, 5, 73, 3, 34, 4, 23, 73]
uniq = sorted(set(original_list))

antecedents = defaultdict(lambda: []) # Reverse mapping
for i, left in enumerate(uniq):
    for right in uniq[i+1:]:
        key = left * left + right * right
        antecedents[key].append((left, right))
# The keys of antecedents are sum of squares

uniq_squares = set([ x * x for x in uniq ])
common_keys = uniq_squares & antecedents.keys()

for key in common_keys:
    sqrt = int(0.5 + key**0.5)
    key_antecedents = antecedents[key]
    for (left, right) in key_antecedents:
        print("Found triplet:", (left, right, sqrt))
```

Comment: Can you explain that defaultdict to me? Is it creating a different empty list each time because python passes by reference?

Comment: @JoshuaNelson Python *never passes by reference*

Comment: Note you can just do `defaultdict(list)` since `list()` already returns `[]`

Comment: `>>> a = {}`

`>>> def f(d):`

`...     d['test'] = True`

`... `

`>>> f(a)`

`>>> a['test']`

True

Comment: ahh I see why I was confused, `defaultdict` requires a `__call__`able function, not a value

Comment: @JoshuaNelson this does not demonstrate call by reference semantics. This would: `>>> a = 'foo'` `>>> def f(&x):` `... x = 'bar'` `... >>> f(a)` `>>> a` `'bar'` The key point is that *assignments to the reference are seen by the caller*.

Comment: Thanks! I also used the idea to have the squares in another list and find the triplets .     import math
number_list = [7,3,8,10,18,5,2,4]

number_list2=[]
for i in number_list:
    number_list2.append(i **2)

for i in range(len(number_list2)):
    for j in range (i+1,len(number_list2)):
        if (number_list2[i]+ number_list2[j]) in number_list2:
            print((number_list2[i],number_list2[j],number_list2[i]+ number_list2[j]))
            print(((math.sqrt(number_list2[i]),(math.sqrt(number_list2[j])),(math.sqrt(number_list2[i]+ number_list2[j])))))

Answer (score 0):

Python code

```
[(a,b,c) for a in original_list for b in original_list for c in original_list if a*a+b*b==c*c]
```

Output:

```
[(3, 4, 5), (4, 3, 5)]
```

Comment: Try doing that with a list longer than 10 numbers.

Comment: If ram is a problem you can use generators instead of lists

    `((a,b,c) for a in original_list for b in original_list for c in original_list if a*a+b*b==c*c)`