# Find primitive pythagorean triplets

Tags: python, pythagorean

Let's get this out of the way: I already had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575117/generating-unique-ordered-pythagorean-triplets/576405) answer here. My approach however is different. I'm leveraging the cantor pairing function and basically mapping the triplets as integers. the complete sequence is as follows:

1) iterate over (i,j) and adding the cantor(i,j) to an array as long as gcd(i,j) == 1 and i < j

2) sort smallest to largest

My rudimentary understanding would have me think that this should return an ordered set of primitive pythagorean  triples, is that not so?

Here's the code:

```
def go(n):
    tmpi = []
    for i in range(1,n):
        for j in range(n%2 +1,n,2):
            if gcd(i,j) == 1:
                if (i+j)%2 == 1:
                    if i < j:
                        tmpi.append(cantor(i,j))
    tmpi.sort()
    return tmpi
```

and the cantor function:

```
def cantor(x,y):
    return int(0.5*(x+y)*(x+y+1)+y)
```

Am I missing something?

Edit:

With this additional code:

```
def lister(li):
    tmp = []
    for i in li:
        tmp.append(list(retTrp(invCant(i))))
    return tmp

def listi2(li):
    for i in li:
        i.sort()

def sorti(li):
    return sorted(li, key=itemgetter(2))

def doall(n):
    tmp = lister(go(n))
    listi2(tmp)
    return sorti(tmp)
```

The input:

```
doall(100)[99]
```

should return

```
[429, 460, 629]
```

but instead the above is returned when the input is

```
doall(100)[100]
```

Hence my question about the order.

Comment: We don't know -- where is your output, and what is wrong with it?  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.

Comment: point taken, I amended the Q :)

Comment: Your posted code still doesn't run, even when I merge the three pieces.

Comment: Just a suggestion: The program could be made more effiicient by changing the structure of your if blocks. Try if ` gcd(i,j) == 1  and (i+j)%2 == 1 and i < j:   tmpi.append(cantor(i,j))`

Comment: Thanks @ThePerson. It somehow did make it more efficient and for some black magic reason it now computes correctly...

Comment: Happy to help !